# Building an XML Schema from a Perl Hash?

Tags: xml, perl, hash, xsd

We're using one huge Perl Hash throughout the life of our application to store all details. We use data in this hash to write to the XML documents in the database. Is it possible to create some sort of XML schema from this hash to validate all the documents in the database against? Is there a Perl module that does something similar?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kwalify](http://p3rl.org/Kwalify) and [Rx](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aRx) are schema languages/validators for (Perl) data structures.

A related useful tool is [dpath](http://p3rl.org/dpath) for accessing items in data structures with a [syntax similar to XPath](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDPath).