# Perl Unit Testing Data Structures

Tags: perl, unit-testing, data-structures

I'm looking for something like is_deeply or Test::Deep's cmp_deeply, but that just checks the keys/types of a data structure, not the values. For example, I care that a key is an array ref of scalars, but not what the values are.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm sure I am not the first one who has had to make sense of varying data structures. I want to test to make sure the "signature" of the data structure is intact, but I care less about the data in it or matching stuff with regex etc.

Comment: The answer is basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622895/building-an-xml-schema-from-a-perl-hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own test functions fairly easily, using the functions provided in [Test::Builder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aBuilder) and [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore).

I have written the test assuming you mean an arrayref of *non-references*, since the only thing you can store in an array is a scalar.  You may want to make adjustments.

```
use Test::Builder;
use Test::More 0.81_01;

sub is_arrayref_of_nonrefs
{
    my $value = shift;

    local $Test::Builder::Level = $Test::Builder::Level + 1;

    return Test::More::ok(0, 'value is an arrayref')
        if not ref $value or ref $value ne 'ARRAY';

    # fail if any references are found in the arrayref
    Test::More::ok((grep { ref } @$value), 'value is an arrayref of non-references');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain [Test::More](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aMore) `isa_ok` method works on references:

```
isa_ok( $array_ref, 'ARRAY' );
```